# Minimal coupling Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, momentum, hamiltonian

A charged particle in an em field can be described by the following Hamiltonian (in CGS units):

$$H = \frac {(\vec{p} \ + \frac {q}{c}\vec{A})^2}{2m} + U(r)$$

But... what does it mean to square the sum of two vectorial operators? Isn't it supposed to be the modulus squared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be understood as this:
$$
(\mathbf{p}+\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A})^2 = (\mathbf{p}+\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A})\cdot (\mathbf{p}+\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A})
= \mathbf{p}^2 + \frac{e^2}{c^2}\mathbf{A}^2 + \frac{e}{c}(\mathbf{p}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{p})
$$

**Remark:** Note that we are working here in the context of the *canonical quantization* - the quantities are replaced by their operators. Thus, one could expand the square *before* quantizing and should obtain the same result (although one would need explicitly order the operators, to make the result Hermitian).

Comment: I thought $A^2$ to be the composition of the same operator: $A(A (\dots))$. It's very different from $(A \cdot A)(\dots)$

Comment: It is... the expression written in the answer says just that

Comment: uhm... $\bf p A$ is not $\bf p \cdot A$, as my professor wrote. And ${\bf p}^2 = - \hbar^2 \boldsymbol \nabla ( \boldsymbol \nabla ( . ))$ is not ${\rm p}^2 = - i \hbar^2 \nabla^2$

Comment: $\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{A} = p_xA_x + p_yA_y + p_zA_z$, i.e., it is understood as a scalar product of two vectors (with operator components). Note that this is still an operator, which needs a function to act upon.

Comment: Sure, but while $\bf p \cdot A$ is a single scalar operator, $\bf p A$ are two distinct vectorial operators. My problem is... idk if, in general, ${\bf A}^2$ is supposed to be intended as $\bf AA$ or $A^2 = \bf A \cdot A$

Comment: It seems to be a matter of notation here: in many cases $\mathbf{p}\mathbf{A}$ means a scalar product, but in some books it may mean a direct product - it depends on the context and on the accepted conventions. Here it is just a scalar ("dot") product.